# Why do I have 2 Tors on my dock?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I have Tor open, which is all the time, this is what appears on my dock (OS X 10.6.8):
* a purple and white onion labeled TorBrowser_en_US
* a green Vidalia onion
* a green Tor globe
* another green Tor globe

One of the Tor globes is the browser I use - it has all my bookmarks.

The other Tor globe is incomplete - it has almost none of my bookmarks. I do remember having an issue trying to export the bookmarks html. I may have dl the browser twice.

But I opened my apps folder and dragged the truncated Tor to the trash and emptied it. It's no longer in my apps folder, but dang, there it is again on my dock! My apps folder now has one green Tor globe and one purple and white onion labeled TorBrowser_en_US.

What's up with that? Is there a way to stop it from happening? I don't think it's causing any glitches in my websurfing, but I don't really know how Tor is supposed to work. For example, I'm thinking it's normal to get search results from several different language sites - predominantly Polish, Romanian, Dutch, and Norwegian - though the results themselves are usually in English.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebooting? You know there is no reason to keep the TBB in your applications folder. It does not need to be installed because its a standalone executable. I would start by opening up a list of your running processes and looking for multiple versions of TBB. It is possible to have multiple Tor instances running on your machine, but there is no reason to do that.

If it were me, I would go to utilities and open terminal, then type
ps aux | grep tor
and it will show you a list of everything running that has the letters tor running. Each process will have a number that goes with it, look through the list until you see the ones used by tbb and type
kill -9 
Where  is the process ID you got from the ps aux | grep command above. 
That way you can kill off everything involving Tor, and hopefully that will get rid of your unwanted shortcut in the bottom.

Comment: Not sure about everything you said because I'm just a writer, and not of code. I have rebooted, but there was no change. You say I don't need tbb in my apps folder, but then what do I do with it? Trash it? Plus I have Firefox and Safari in my apps folder. How can they work without being in the folder? As long as I've had computers my browsers have been in that folder. Obviously I'm unclear on, oh, all *kinds* of concepts here. Anyway, my Activity Monitor showed one Tor globe and the Vidalia purple and white onion (and believe me, I have no idea what Vidalia is or what it's for). So I quit Tor

Answer (score 0):

I asked another question in Troubleshooting that arose when I decided to uninstall and reinstall Tor to get rid of the weird almost duplicates (different versions). Then all day today I couldn't access the Tor site to download. Tried everything, nothing worked. Read how Comcast was ordering customers to stop using Tor or lose service, wondered if TWC was doing the same thing. Read how changing the DNS might help. Didn't know what a DNS is, but saw that Google has public ones. Read that I could change just for  my computer, not my home network (my wife wouldn't appreciate it). So I did that, and immediately I was able to access the website, dl the latest Tor (I think), Firefox ESR 24.8, and am back up, hopefully without creepy government types following me around - I don't do illegal stuff, but I really despise Big Brother.